# Outlook not showing names on birthdates

Tags: calendar, outlook

After installing Salesforce for outlook....my users are seeing items on their calendar that are customer birthdays but it does not show their name. For example...it will say "  's Birthday is on Oct. 14" when it should say "Jim Miller's Birthday is on Oct. 14". The errors seems to be with the Salesforce for outlook. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do the sync'd contact records that are in Outlook include names with birthdate values on them?

Comment: I am syncing with Salesforce records...so the data is from Salesforce. It has all the data in corresponding fields. It looks like it uses First Name and Last Name to create the birthday label.

Comment: Problem was fixed. We were syncing outlook to google and Salesforce to outlook. Had to map Salefore sync to calendar created by salesforce then sync...remove all " 's Birthdays"... then had to map back to orginal outlook calendar. Problem solved.